# How can I get the source code of a class used in ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I am coding this:

```
IdentityResult result = new IdentityResult("Username not found");
```

I can see this is one of the constructors in here;

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
{
//
// Summary:
//     Represents the result of an identity operation
public class IdentityResult
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Failure constructor that takes error messages
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   errors:
    public IdentityResult(IEnumerable<string> errors);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Failure constructor that takes error messages
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   errors:
    public IdentityResult(params string[] errors);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Constructor that takes whether the result is successful
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   success:
    protected IdentityResult(bool success);
```

But I can't find the source code for this. Is the source code available?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/daa50df87feb9f1b59858a22f00a2984996738c6/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/IdentityResult.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily download the source code from the [Github repository](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity) (future releases and beta) or [CodePlex](http://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Readme.markdown) (for older versions) since ASP.NET Identity (and a lot of other parts of ASP.NET) are open source nowadays.

Visual Studio only knows the outline of a class when the action source isn't available on the machine itself (hence you get this view when clicking F12).

Comment: Actually Github repo contains v3 which is not released yet and is aimed towards ASP.Net 5. Currently released Identity 2.2 is on Codeplex: http://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/

Comment: @trailmax Indeed. Thanks for the heads-up. Updated!

Answer (score -1):

you can use telerik decompiler its free

http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx

try to search class on this as well. 
http://dotnetframework.org/Search.aspx

Comment: Why decompile if you can download the source code itself?

Comment: it help you see quickly whats in the class instead of downloading and then searching for what you looking for..

Comment: No need to download and search, the repository is very clear: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/daa50df87feb9f1b59858a22f00a2984996738c6/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/IdentityResult.cs.